# Phonegap: Will my mobile app 'feel' faster or slower once ported to phonegap?

Tags: html, cordova, mobile, memory-management, responsive-design

So I'm designing everything in mobile Safari and I know that phonegap is essentially a stripped webview but...

**Question:** Will my application will run better in phonegap? *(revised below)*

a)I imagine my navigation and core app will load faster as the scripts and images are on the hard drive. Is this True?

b)I assume since they've been working on it for 2 years now that they may have made some optimizations to make it quicker than just an average safari window. Is this true?

(Assuming both html5/js/css code bases are pretty much the same and app is running on iOS.)

**Update:** Sorry, I meant to compare apples to slightly different apples.

---

**Question 1 revised:**  Will my app see any performance benefits running with in a phonegap environment vs  standard mobile safari? (compare mobile - to mobile)

1b) In what ways, other than loading time has phonegap optimized performance over standard mobile safari?

**Follow ups:**
1) Are there any pitfalls, other than large libraries, that may cause phonegap to suffer a serious performance hit vs stand mobile safari?

2) Can I mix native and webview rendering? (i.e the top half of my app is rendered in with html/css/js and the bottom half native)

Comment: I think the answer will depend on your app. Just run a test.

Comment: you´re comparing apples and pears. Phonegap is basically just a javascript library. There is no run time environment or whatsoever. the performace depends completely on how fast your device is able to execute the javascripts. On old devices, this can result in a terrible performance, and performance optimizations of phonegap won´t change that in any aspect, no matter how good they are.

Comment: Sorry about that, I clarified a bit.

Comment: Bah, I wanna have answers to your revised questions. I would like to know if basic java script calculations code is running slower on the same iPhone on mobile web vs in an app. For example if a loop doing a math calculation a 1000 times is slower on any of the two? like apa = 1; banan = 1.5; while(apa < 1000) { banan = banan^banan^banan; apa++; }..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are targeting the latest version of iOS performance shouldn't be an issue. Mobile safari gets new features before the webview control does, but now that both versions have things like hardware accelerated rendering, it doesn't matter too much.

The only performance improvement you are likely to see is the obvious one from loading files locally - it's the same code running on the same device.

Where needed you can mix native code in as much as you want. I generally try to keep that to a minimum though - debugging in a browser is a lot easier than deploying the code to a device and using the native debugger.